# Advanced two player rules clarification for 7 Wonders

Tags: 7-wonders

Perhaps I overlooked the following when reading the rules, but I don't recall these questions being addressed in the two-player advanced rules for 7 Wonders:

Can the free city build its wonder, or must it only build cards?

What does the free city do if it can't afford to build anything, since it isn't allowed to discard for coins?

Comment: here is an idea: set up 4 cities and you play two each and use the team rules, i.e. victories points for military victor and defeats are doubled. Doves only half the military points gained.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the rules, the free city can take any action a 'normal' player can take with a restriction on discarding cards for money. The free city CAN build a wonder. In fact, a good strategy for the third city is to use it to bury cards your opponent might want, e.g. by building the wonder.

The free city CAN also discard a card for money, but only if no other playable card is available. Therefore, if the city has no playable cards, you can choose a card to discard and the free city gains the coins.

(Rules are here: http://www.rprod.com/en/7W-rules.html)

Comment: I must have missed the clarification in the rules:

Clariﬁcation : The Free City cannot discard a card to get 3 coins unless it cannot play a card. The player must then choose, when possible, a card which can be played by the Free City (structure construction or wonder building 
stage).

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!

Comment: Another useful strategy is to have the free city buy resources from you so you can get money. Having the free city buy a resource from you to build a wonder and get a discard is a double advantage.